# Jordan Bases Linear Dependence?

Tags: linear-algebra, jordan-normal-form

Say we have a Jordan form for $A$, called $J$. Two different people come up with two different bases for $J$; person A comes up with $V$ = {$v_1, v_2, ... , v_n$}, and P.B. comes up with $W$ = {$w_1, w_2, ... , w_n$}. How many pairs of vectors in $V$ and $W$ are we sure are scalar multiples of each other?

Comment: Perhaps none: if the eigenspaces are all of dimension two, for exampl,e (i.e., the corresponding eigenvalues of *geometric multiplicty* two), then for each pair belonging to the same eigenspace in one of the basis there's a pair in the other basis belonging to the same eigenspace, but we don't need none of these to be a scalar multiple of the other ones. Now, if an eigenvalues has geoemtric dimension 1, then yes...can you see why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There does not have to be any such pair. For example, if $A=I$ is the identity map, it's matrix with respect to any basis of the vector space is identity matrix, which is Jordan. And for any basis 
$$\{e_1,\dots,e_n\}$$
we can find another that contain no vector colinear with $e_1, e_2, \ldots$ or $e_n$, for example
$$\{e_1+e_2,e_1-e_2,e_1+e_2+e_3,\ldots,e_1+\cdots + e_n\}.$$